# How to create new instances of a timer Task instead of canceling and restarting it all over?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, timertask

Well the thing is that I have a project where I have to make a game on java. In my game there's a spaceship that shoots lasers. I have the mechanics for shooting the laser more or less figured out but I am currently using a timer task to make the laser fly through the JFrame and give the impression a laser was shot.

Problem is that TimerTask seems to bug out as soon as I start shooting many times.

The main **goal is to move an object across the screen at a given speed**.

Is there something else I could do to achieve this? Is there a better way to implement this? 
I appreciate all the help I could get, Thanks.
Here is some of the code:

```
public Space() {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                repaint();
                x = e.getX()-spaceFighterIcon.getIconHeight()/2;
                y = e.getY()-spaceFighterIcon.getIconWidth()/2;

            }
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                repaint();
                x = e.getX()-spaceFighterIcon.getIconHeight()/2; //Positions the cursor on the middle of the spaceShip and viceVersa 
                y = e.getY()-spaceFighterIcon.getIconWidth()/2; 

            }
        }
        );
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(timerRunning = true){
                laserTimer.cancel();
                laserTimer.purge();
                laserFired = false;
                }
                if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){ // Gets where the laser is going to be shot from 
                    repaint();
                    laserX = e.getX()-spaceFighterIcon.getIconWidth()/6; 
                    laserY = e.getY();
                    laserFired = true;
                }
                if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){

                }
                if(SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(e)){

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        this.graphics = g;
        super.paintComponent(g);

        spaceFighterIcon.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
        if(laserFired == true){
            shootLaser();
        }
    }
    public void shootLaser(){
        laserIcon.paintIcon(this, graphics, laserX, laserY-50); // paints the laser
        laserTimer = new Timer();
        laserTimer.schedule(new AnimateLasers(), 0, 200); // Timer to move the laser across the frame
        timerRunning = true;
        repaint();
    }
    public void lasers(){
        laserY = laserY-1; // function to move the laser 
        if(laserY <= 0){
            laserTimer.cancel();
            laserTimer.purge();
        }
    }
    public class AnimateLasers extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            lasers(); 
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't maintain a reference to the `Graphics` context outside of the paint method. Consider using a Swing `Timer` instead. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Im really a newbie at this. I started 3 months ago. I have not used swingTimers yet. I will most def take a good look at them. and by a reference to the graphics context do you mean to get rid of the  public void shootLaser(){ method? I will try with an implementation of the swing timer and I ll be back with results =)

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Your component will be told when it should repaint it self by the system (via the call to the `paintComponent` method), essentially, you use the time to update the location of the "laser" and call `repaint`, where you paint the laser

Comment: I just want to say thank you for your help the swing timer worked like a charm. thanks a lot. can you put your comment as an answer to my question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `java.util.Timer`.

Swing `Timer` is safer to use with Swing, as it executes it ticks within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Also take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Don't maintain a reference to the Graphics context outside of the paint method.  Your component will be told when it should repaint it self by the system (via the call to the `paintComponent` method), essentially, you use the time to update the location of the "laser" and call `repaint`, then paint the laser within the `paintComponent` when it's called by the paint system